# how to get date format for excel using xlrd?

Tags: xlrd

Our  requirement is like to import data from excel and display in web. while importing I m able to convert it into any format(like dd-mm-yy) but requirement is like it should display the same format as defined by user.

So if can get the formatting info, we can format using datetime module pf python.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you already tried? SO won't write your code for you, and you're unlikely to get help if you haven't already made an honest attempt yourself. If you've tried something, please edit your question to include your code. If not, go and try to solve your problem yourself, then come back and ask if you run into specific difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

First verify oledb connection string

```
 conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Pricing2.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;""
```

To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data type columns...

```
Range rg = (Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Cells[1,1];
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
```

this used for validate column date type or not.

Before Save using method in C#

```
 Datetime.TryParseExact();
```

That method return Datetime ,First leran that method before try it.